# Primary Zygote (64-bit) only starts the System Services? And all Android apps are 32-bit?

Tags: boot, aosp, services

As far as I know Zygote is started by `app_process64` and `app_process32` where 64 is for primary zygote that starts system services because of `start-system-server` flag.

As we can see below in `static void main` method of `frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/os/ZygoteInit.java`, it checks for `start-system-server` flag, `run` the forked System Server and exits due to `return;` statement below it, and never running the `runSelectLoop` that actually goes into infinite loop listening to connections that request to launch new applications. Only `app_process32` without `start-system-server` flag will not enter the control statement to `run` the forked System Server, and instead, runs the `runSelectLoop`. Does it mean that all system services are inherently 64-bit while all Android apps are inherently 32-bit?

This code is from AOSP branch: `Android-14.0.0_r21`:

```
// redacted above code

zygoteServer = new ZygoteServer(isPrimaryZygote);

if (startSystemServer) {
    Runnable r = forkSystemServer(abiList, zygoteSocketName, zygoteServer);

    // {@code r == null} in the parent (zygote) process, and {@code r != null} in the
    // child (system_server) process.
    if (r != null) {
        r.run();
        return;
    }
}

Log.i(TAG, "Accepting command socket connections");

// The select loop returns early in the child process after a fork and
// loops forever in the zygote.
caller = zygoteServer.runSelectLoop(abiList);

// redacted code below
```

Comment: Are you sure this is not a misinterpretation? May be 64 and 32 means can execute only 64 but and can execute 32 (and 64) bit software. This would make sense as system services are defined by the manufacturer so on a 64 bit device I would assume all system services are 64 bit. But user apps can be 32 or 64 bit so the run in app_process32 (assuming the used CPU and the platform still has the 32 but capability which is not true for Google's recent Pixel phones).

Answer (score 1):

The `runSelectLoop` will actually be run by `app_process64` as well and not simply exit.

Let's take a look at this excerpt of the `forkSystemServer` method, called in your code snippet when `startSystemServer` is true, to see why:

```
private static Runnable forkSystemServer(String abiList, String socketName,
        ZygoteServer zygoteServer) {
    // ...

    int pid;

    try {
        // ...

        pid = Zygote.forkSystemServer(
                parsedArgs.mUid, parsedArgs.mGid,
                parsedArgs.mGids,
                parsedArgs.mRuntimeFlags,
                null,
                parsedArgs.mPermittedCapabilities,
                parsedArgs.mEffectiveCapabilities);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }

    /* For child process */
    if (pid == 0) {
        // ...

        return handleSystemServerProcess(parsedArgs);
    }

    /* For parent process */
    return null;
}
```

I removed most of the code and kept only the relevant part for clarity.
As you can see, the method will fork the current process and return some data in the child process, while it will return `null` in the parent process.

This means that both the child process (`system_server`) and the main process (`zygote64`) process will continue execution in the code snippet you included in the question:

```
Runnable r = forkSystemServer(abiList, zygoteSocketName, zygoteServer);

// {@code r == null} in the parent (zygote) process, and {@code r != null} in the
// child (system_server) process.
if (r != null) {
    r.run();
    return;
}
```

Now, in the forked `system_server` process, the call to `forkSystemServer` returned some object. The process will therefore enter the `if` and execute `r.run()` before returning. `zygoteServer.runSelectLoop(abiList)` will therefore never be executed **in the child process (system_server)**.

However, in the parent process, the call to `forkSystemServer` returned `null`. The process will therefore not enter the `if` and continue, executing `zygoteServer.runSelectLoop(abiList)`.

This is also what is mentioned in comment in your code snippet.

In case you are not yet convinced, listing the running processes on your device will clearly show you that both `zygote64` and `system_server` are running alongside the 32-bit version of `zygote`:

```
# ps -e | grep -E "zygote|system_server"
root           979     1 6102692  65188 do_sys_poll         0 S zygote64
root           980     1 1754948  18020 do_sys_poll         0 S zygote
system        2164   979 14310660 308548 do_epoll_wait      0 S system_server
```

So to finally answer the question:
No, Android applications are not inherently 32-bit.
`zygote64` will be used to run 64-bit applications.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. In modern Android versions, starting with Android 8.0 (Oreo), the system_server process is started by the zygote64 process. This change was introduced to support 64-bit architectures while maintaining backward compatibility with 32-bit architectures.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).